# Why is my Custom Action Bar White, and not the Specified Color?

Tags: android, xml, colors, android-actionbar

I am creating an Android app, and I have customized my action bar using this code-

**action_bar_styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>

<style name="Theme.Base" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#f1f1f1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/notesPrimaryBackgroundColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/notesSecondaryBackgroundColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/notesColorBackgroundAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/notesBackgroundColor</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
<color name="notesPrimaryBackgroundColor">#009688</color>
<color name="notesSecondaryBackgroundColor">#004D40</color>
<color name="notesColorBackgroundAccent">#FF9922</color>
<color name="notesBackgroundColor">#FAFAFA</color>
<color name="notesPrimaryTextColor">#FAFAFA</color>
<color name="notesBody">#FAFAFA</color>
<color name="notesCardBody">#EBEBEB</color>
<color name="notesSecondaryTextColor">#656565</color>
<color name="notesDropBoxSeparator">#C1C1C1</color>
<color name="notesSelectionTickColor">#455EDE</color>
<color name="notesImageBackground">#C1C1C1</color>
</resources>
```

I selected Theme.Base as the theme in the Android Manifest, and the action bar color shows up in the designers, but when I run my app on my Samsung tablet, the action bar is white, and everything else is normal. Could this be because I specified the action bar color somewhere else as well, or is it because I didn't specify its color correctly? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the code

```
<style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

hope that helps.

Specifying

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
```

and you made this guy parent of your app theme which in turn forces it to have no action bar.

Comment: I updated my code, now the action bar does show, but right on top of it is a white bar. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Cool. Sure George, that is the status bar thing. If your test device API version  > 21, it will show as colorPrimaryDark value. If not you have to manually set.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar));
}
```

[Helpful notes](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html).

Comment: It was acctually '<item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>' that was making that white bar with a title in it appear. You did solve my problem though. Thanks!